# Type mismatch with Scala implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm trying to use implicits in Scala.

```
object TypeClasses extends App {
  trait HTMLWritable {
    def toHTML: String
  }

  case class User(name: String, age: Int, email: String) extends HTMLWritable {
    override def toHTML: String = s"<div>$name ($age yo) <a href=$email/> </div>"
  }

  val john = User("John", 32, "john@rockthejvm.com")
  trait HTMLSerializer[T] {
    def serialize(value: T): String
  }

  object UserSerializer extends HTMLSerializer[User] {
    def serialize(user: User): String = s"<div>${user.name} (${user.age} yo) <a href=${user.email}/> </div>"
  }

  implicit class HTMLEnrichment[T](value: T) {
    def toHTML(serializer: HTMLSerializer[T]): String = serializer.serialize(value)
  }

  println(john.toHTML(UserSerializer))
}
```

this code won't compile:

```
Error:(41, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : lectures.part4implicits.TypeClasses.UserSerializer.type
 required: Int
  println(john.toHTML(UserSerializer))
```

I'm having trouble understanding the message, because according to IntelliJ, `john.toHTML` is a call to the `toHTML` method on the `HTMLEnrichment` class, which expects a `HTMLSerializer`, which is what I have given it. Nowhere have I defined a `toHTML` method which requires an `Int`.

Comment: The problem is that since your `User` already has a `toHTML` method, it will use it, instead of the **extension method**. And, since that method does not take parameter, the compiler interpretes that as calling the `apply` method on the return of `toHTML`, which is a `String` whose `apply` method return a `Character` by index. That is why the compiler warns about the `Int` - Try with another name _(e.g. `toHTML2`)_ or removing the normal `toHTML`, or creating another `User` class, etc.

Comment: BTW, usually an **implicit class** is combined with a [**value class**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) to avoid instantiation. Also, usually the `serializer` would be an implicit argument, and the `UserSerializer` would be implicit too. Since one usually do not want to pass it explicitly. - Also, case classes should be final. And, in general, for simple use cases like this one, is better to use **implicit vals _(with explicit type signature)_** instead of an object. `implicit val UserSerializer: HTMLSerializer[User] = new HTMLSerializer[User] { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you've accidentally overloaded the `toHTML` method. The error you're getting is because `String.apply` returns the character at a given index, which is why you are getting that error about the `Int`.

Intelij is not always efficient at picking out this kind of shadowing. It's a good idea to keep implicit mechanisms away from domain model, e.g de-couple specialised serialisations into implicits, just like you are doing with:

```
  implicit object UserSerializer extends HTMLSerializer[User] {
    def serialize(user: User): String = s"<div>${user.name} (${user.age} yo) <a href=${user.email}/> </div>"
  }
```

Then remove everything from your `user`, and maybe add a helper.

```
trait HTMLSerializer {
  def toHTML: String
}

object HTMLSerializer {
  // if you put this here you don't need to explicitly import it.
  implicit class HTMLEnrichment[T](val value: T) extends AnyVal {
    def toHTML(implicit serializer: HTMLSerializer[T]): String = 
      serializer.serialize(value)
  }
}
```

This means you can simply get the same effect as having a companion method, but you can keep everything nicely de-coupled, and you don't risk having those kinds of shading effects.

Comment: First, `UserSerializer` must be implicit. Second, `value` should had been a **val** in order to make it a value class _(right now it doesn't even compile)_. Also, what is the purpose of the `HTMLWritable` trait?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You're right thanks for spotting things, I copy pasted in a hurry.